# Current debbuger framework configuration

Tags: debugging, frameworks, configuration, version

Somenone knows why I get this message when I'm debugging an attached ASP.NET 2.0 application ?

*An unhandled exception was raised from Microsoft .NET Framework v1.0, 1.1, or 2.0, but the current debugger is configured to debug Microsoft .NET Framework v4.0 code. Examine the exception using the SOS tool.*

I have .NET 4.0 installed, the application are running in a a IIS7.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using visual studio 2010

When attaching to the process for debugging you should select the type of code:

The default is managed (v4.0) code

Other options are:

- Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0)
- Native
- Script
- SilverLight
- T-SQL
- workflow

Comment: What if you're not attaching to an already-running process, but trying to launch with the Visual Studio 'start debugging' button?  Where is the setting for this?  It's not a choice on the project properties page where you specify configuration, external program, working directory, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you've attached to your debugger, you need to check the right framework version. For example, click `Debug` -> `Attach to Process` and it will bring up the Attach to Process window. It should have a `Select` button to select the type of code to debug. Select the `Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0) code` option and then attach to the process you want to debug.